# create week function, but instead of Sunday start day of the week, Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server

Anyone know of a script, that creates a week table, that is based on Monday as the start day of the week and not Sunday? For MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the way SQL Server sets the first day of the week using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx if that helps?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I left the script which I had, the same way, but I altered the DATEFIRST to 1. Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is putting every sunday to the week before, with week=0->week=52

Comment: What I do is I create a numbers table, to generate the days of the year, and then use date part/add functions to get the weeks etc. But there is always something that seems to mess up when I alter the function to make it start from Mondays. I cannot seem to get it right